# Is there a Dependency Injection Framework for Delphi with attribute-based injection?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection

I would love to be able to code in Delphi this way, simply annotating a field:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    [Inject]
    Factory: ISomeFactory;
    ...
  end;
```

or by attributing a setter

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FFactory: ISomeFactory;

    [Inject]
    procedure SetFactory(const AFactory: ISomeFactory);
    ...
  public
    property Factory: ISomeFactory read FFactory write SetFactory;
  end;
```

---

The background: I am moving old code to a service-oriented architecture and find that referencing the service layer always leads to constructs like

```
DataModule1.ServiceLayerInstance1.SubSystemN.InvokeSomething(Params, ...);
```

which could be much shorter like

```
type
  Form1 = class(TForm1)
  private
    [Inject]
    SubsystemN: ISubsystemN;
    ...
  end;
  ...
  SubsystemN.InvokeSomething(Params, ...);
```

Comment: Prevent using attribute based injection. Use constructor injection where possible.

Comment: @Steven That probably depends on the dependency.  If the class absolutely will not work without it, then yes, constructor is more appropriate.  If it can reasonably work without it, property injection is one way to make it optional.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: But still you shouldn't have to use an attribute for using property injection. This forces the application to take a dependency on the container, but the application should be oblivious.

Comment: I agree with Steven IF the field cannot be set otherwise. That would make the class untestable and cause a dependency on the container. Otherwise I see the Inject attribute as simply metadata that helps the container creating it. But the class still has to be fully functional without the use of the container imo.

Comment: @Steven Attributes seem to be good enough for MEF in the .NET world (granted it's built into the framework itself).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is. The Delphi Spring Framework

http://www.spring4d.com/

does precisely this. It has an [Inject] attribute.

One caveat -- to use it, you need to include the Spring unit in your code where the attribute is defined.  Otherwise, the compiler will ignore the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this goal with the Emballo OpenSource project.

See the project on Google Code:
http://code.google.com/p/emballo/wiki/WhyDependencyInjection